# How to attach element to another Ajax component

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

All, Forgive me I am not familiar with the ASP.NET Ajax. I knew the method [Create](http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/ClientReference/Sys/ComponentClass/ComponentCreateMethod.aspx) is attaching an html element to ajax component. But I don't know how to detach it from the current component . and attach another one.

Let's say there is a element `ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_UserRegistration_txbPassword1` has been attached to a component type `AccelaWebControlExtender.HelperBehavior`, and the created component id is `ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_UserRegistration_txbPassword1_helper_bhv`. The code looks like below. please review it .

```
Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(AccelaWebControlExtender.HelperBehavior, {"closeTitle":"Close","id":"ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_UserRegistration_txbPassword1_helper_bhv","isRTL":false,"title":"Help"}, null, null, $get("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_UserRegistration_txbPassword1"));
});
```

I think firstly I should retrieve the component by id, then do the detach and attach work. Hope someone can give me some help.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research, I found It is called `Extend Web server control that encapsulates a client behavior` in Asp.net Ajax, And I found the attachment of component is done by Asp.net automatically . We can see the `Sys.Application.add_init(function()` code is generated in the aspx page by Asp.net automatically. So if we want to customize the original behavior of Web Server Control, I believe it can be made in the Javascript OOP way(old and same).

For example :
If the original behavior code is blow.

```
// Register the namespace for the control.
Type.registerNamespace('Samples');

//
// Define the behavior properties.
//
Samples.FocusBehavior = function(element) { 
    Samples.FocusBehavior.initializeBase(this, [element]);

    this._highlightCssClass = null;
    this._nohighlightCssClass = null;
}

//
// Create the prototype for the behavior.
//
Samples.FocusBehavior.prototype = {
    initialize : function() {
        Samples.FocusBehavior.callBaseMethod(this, 'initialize');

        $addHandlers(this.get_element(), 
                     { 'focus' : this._onFocus,
                       'blur' : this._onBlur },
                     this);

        this.get_element().className = this._nohighlightCssClass;
    },

    dispose : function() {
        $clearHandlers(this.get_element());

        Samples.FocusBehavior.callBaseMethod(this, 'dispose');
    },

    //
    // Event delegates
    //
    _onFocus : function(e) {
        if (this.get_element() && !this.get_element().disabled) {
            this.get_element().className = this._highlightCssClass;          
        }
    },

    _onBlur : function(e) {
        if (this.get_element() && !this.get_element().disabled) {
            this.get_element().className = this._nohighlightCssClass;          
        }
    },


    //
    // Behavior properties
    //
    get_highlightCssClass : function() {
        return this._highlightCssClass;
    },

    set_highlightCssClass : function(value) {
        if (this._highlightCssClass !== value) {
            this._highlightCssClass = value;
            this.raisePropertyChanged('highlightCssClass');
        }
    },

    get_nohighlightCssClass : function() {
        return this._nohighlightCssClass;
    },

    set_nohighlightCssClass : function(value) {
        if (this._nohighlightCssClass !== value) {
            this._nohighlightCssClass = value;
            this.raisePropertyChanged('nohighlightCssClass');
        }
    }
}

// Optional descriptor for JSON serialization.
Samples.FocusBehavior.descriptor = {
    properties: [   {name: 'highlightCssClass', type: String},
                    {name: 'nohighlightCssClass', type: String} ]
}

// Register the class as a type that inherits from Sys.UI.Control.
Samples.FocusBehavior.registerClass('Samples.FocusBehavior', Sys.UI.Behavior);

if (typeof(Sys) !== 'undefined') Sys.Application.notifyScriptLoaded();
```

I think we can override some of the methods of the Javascript Object `Samples.FocusBehavior` and it's prototype object to achieve customization.

For example .

I can override `Samples.FocusBehavior.prototype._onFocus` in the script like this.

```
Samples.FocusBehavior.prototype._onFocus = function (e) {
    alert('test');
    if (this.get_element() && !this.get_element().disabled) {
        this.get_element().className = this._highlightCssClass;
    }
};
```

Just make sure this code is parsed after original one by Browser.
I am not sure if this is the right way to make it . I hope someone can help to verify it .Thank you very much.

Here is a [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386403.aspx) of it. please review it .
Cheers.